# Can't parse JSON data to .NET DateTime

Tags: c#, json, json.net

It's pretty simple. I have a string

```
string s = "/Date(1474408920000)/"
```

And I want to convert it to a date:

```
DateTime date = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DateTime>(s);
```

But I get the error:

"Error parsing comment. Expected: *, got D. Path '', line 1, position 1."

**What's going on here?**

Thanks for your help!

Comment: In JavaScript, anything between two '/' represents a regular expression.

Comment: You'll want to use Parse or tryparse... but first what date format is that? Epoch, Linux / Windows? mmssssDDmmyyyy ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json string is not valid but can easily be fixed by surrounding it with `"`

```
string s = @"""/Date(1474408920000)/""";
```

Now  `DateTime date = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DateTime>(s);` will work

Comment: Thanks. Very helpful. By the way, make sure you use .ToLocalTime() if you're trying to compare it to other DateTimes in your program!

Answer (score 0):

```
        var LogDate = new DateTime(2016, 9, 20, 22, 2, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

        string JsonDate = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(LogDate, new JsonSerializerSettings {
            DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat
        });

        Console.WriteLine(JsonDate);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Output from this code gives you a proper JSON date format:

```
"\/Date(1474408920000)\/"
```

So your string should look like this:

```
string s = "\"\\/Date(1474408920000)\\/\"";
```

Answer (score 0):

try serializing the DateTime obj to JSON using below code.

```
        var dateTime = DateTime.Now;
        var jsonDate = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dateTime, 
                            new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings() { 
                                DateFormatHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat, 
                                DateParseHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateParseHandling.DateTime });
```

`jsonDate` would hold this value `"\"\\/Date(1474408920000)\\/\""` or something in this format.
Now deserialize your json date string using below code.

```
var dateObj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DateTime>(dateString, 
                            new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings() { 
                                DateParseHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateParseHandling.DateTime, 
                                DateFormatHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat });
```