# Parsing a JSON date into a C# DateTime

Tags: c#, json, datetime

i have an API that get information from targetProcess and put that information in sql tables.

the issue comes when a targetProcess field is date because i recieved it as json date `"/Date(1409202000000-0500 )/"`.

How can i convert this json date to Datetime in c#?

i have been trying add extra quotes like the asnwer in this [StackOverflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39669511/cant-parse-json-data-to-net-datetime) but it doesnt work.

i tried replace the the word Date for only use `1409202000000-0500` in

```
DateTime dotNetDate = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
dotNetDate = dotNetDate.AddMilliseconds(Convert.ToInt64(1409202000000-0500)
```

i use too JSON.NET as bellow

```
string sa = "/Date(1409202000000-0500 )/"
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
dt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DateTime>(sa);
```

but it doesnt work too,

so the question is....How can i convert this json date to Datetime in c#?

Comment: What serializer are you using to deserialize your JSON?  [tag:json.net]?  [tag:javascriptserializer]?  [tag:datacontractjsonserialize]?  Or something else?

Comment: i using json.NET

Comment: Why don't you create date manually? And is the response giving you date and time in milliseconds?

Comment: sorry, i dont understand, the date i get in this format from targetProcess Api and i dont get access to manipule, it supponsed to the date in targetProcess its in datetime format too

Comment: If I correct your string literal as shown in the post to which you linked, your code works.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/GiP6Sy.   What exactly is your real problem?

Comment: yeah, but in this case, how i can add the String.Replace or String.Insert to pass from this "/Date(1409202000000-0500 )/" to this @"""/Date(1409202000000-0500 )/""", dont forget that i cant write the character manually beacuase its a list of date that i get from api and stored in database

Comment: Upvoted, here's a fork of @dbc, https://dotnetfiddle.net/Z9ABCx

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to manually wrap your string "programatically" in quotes to ensure that it properly formatted correctly:

```
string sa = @"""" + "/Date(1409202000000-0500 )/" + @"""";
DateTime dt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DateTime>(sa);
```

If you need to call it multiple times (which it seems like you do), just move the wrapping responsibility to a method:

```
public string WrapStringInQuotes(string input)
{
    return @"""" + input + @"""";
}
```

Comment: Upvoted, here's a fork of @dbc from the comments, https://dotnetfiddle.net/Z9ABCx

Comment: If you have access to the newer versions of C# you can simplify to,

`var dateTime = @"""/Date(1573074780000-0500)/""";`

I'm still baffled as to why the default conversion doesn't work without the added quotes.

Answer (score 5):

The issue is with your date string. 
instead of

```
string sa = "/Date(1409202000000-0500 )/"
```

try

```
string sa = @"""/Date(1409202000000-0500)/""";
```

Change your code :

```
 string sa = @"""/Date(1409202000000-0500)/""";
            DateTime dt = new DateTime();
            dt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DateTime>(sa);
            // dt = "2014-08-28 3.00.00 PM"
```

Comment: thanks! i solved write
string sa = "/Date(1409202000000-0500 )/";
sa2 = @"""" + sa2 + @"""";

Answer (score 0):

Here you have my function. There is even a possibility that you can get a shorter number for the Json date like in OpenweatherAPI for sunrise and sunset, then in this case you need to multiplicate with 1000. My function handle both scenarios.

```
    public static DateTime GetDateTimeFromJSON(long jsonDateTime, bool shorter = false)
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DateTime>($"\"\\/Date({ (shorter ? jsonDateTime * 1000 : jsonDateTime) })\\/\"", new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat
        }).ToLocalTime();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use my function it does not need any third party reference.

```
    private DateTime JSONdateTime2dateTime(long JSONdatetimelong)
    {
        long DT_Tic = (JSONdatetimelong + 62135607600000) * 10000;
        return new DateTime(DT_Tic);
    }
```