DateTime Parsing
I'm having trouble parsing a string into a readable DateTime format. This is what I want to do. I have a json object that returns a field of DateTime with the following format. "/Date(1733889000000-0800)/". Below is the code of how I want it to display

// I am parsing a list of json objects but for simplicity lets assume it is just one entity
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(list[selected].DateTime, "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
// The above code should parse to this 12-10-2024 9:33pm


When I Console.WriteLine that particular field it will display like this. 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM, which I know for a fact that is incorrect.
My question is how do I parse this format "/Date(1733889000000-0800)/" into something like this format 12-10-2024 9:33pm? Below is a photo of how the json object looks like.


"// The above code should parse to this 12-10-2024 9:33pm" - no, the above code will interpret the date string in list[selected].DateTime as being in the format MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm and use that to parse it as a DateTime object (which has no human-readable value, unless you instinctively understand Ticks). Dates and times as strings can have a human-readable format like MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm, but DateTime, etc. has no such concept.

What you have in your string is /Date(1733889000000-0800)/, which is the Unix Epoch time value in milliseconds combined with the time offset in hours (8 hours behind UTC). You have two questions: 1. how to convert this into a DateTime, and 2. how to format the DateTime as a string in the desired format.

For question 1, you have some solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43130444/parsing-a-json-date-into-a-c-sharp-datetime
